# Sort firebase Recycleview real-time database base on post with most likes in last 24 hours

Tags: android, firebase

How can I sort Recycleview base on post that has the most likes within the last 24 hours, I am currently storing likes in my real-time firebase database here is image for the structure of my database[image-databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRAE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't mean sort recycler-view. You would probably be better off sorting the data in your realtime database call by likes and date then your recycler-view would be built in that same order.
See more info and examples in the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

```
String myUserId = getUid();
Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
        .orderByChild("likes");
myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});
```

You can also filter the call via startAt(), startAfter(), endAt(), endBefore(), and equalTo() etc etc. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: The article is referenced is helpful. So how can I use this method with the code you gave "startAfter()"

Comment: .orderByChild("likes"). startAfter('XXXX')

Comment: Thanks this puts me in the right direction I know how to implement it now with this. I have done many research but this answer best puts me on  track